# Error al buscar null en una objeto

Tags: javascript, function

Hola muchachos espero que estén muy bien, tengo el siguiente problema. En el siguiente objeto

```
"Customer": {
            "Atention": null
            }
```

necesito extraer el valor de `"Atention"` en una función, pero este valor es dinámico y varía, pero siempre tendrá la palabra 'CARTERA'. Para ello estoy usando la siguiente función

```
function ObtenerValor () {
var data = JSON.parse(body)  //Estoy omitiendo la ruta de la respuesta del JSON
var Atention1 = null;
var cadena = data.WSResponseBody.Customer.Atention;  //está es la ruta del objeto `Atention` en la respuesta del JSON
var palabra = 'CARTERA';
var index = cadena.indexOf(palabra);

if(index >= 0) {
    return Atention1 = "la palabra existe";
} else {
    return Atention1 = "la palabra no existe dentro de la cadena";
}
}

ObtenerValor ();
```

Y funciona pero cuando el objeto `Atention` tiene un valor diferente de null, cuando viene en null, me sale el siguiente error
`TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'indexOf')`

Agradecería cualquier ayuda :)

Comment: Puedes hacer un console.log(data) (luego parsear el json) y mostrar los resultados

Comment: No puedes leer las propiedades de una referencia `null`. Verifica que `cadena` no sea `null` antes de usar `cadena.indexOf` y problema listo. Por cierto, la variable `Atention1` es innecesaria si vas a devolverla en el mismo lugar que la asignas.

Comment: Lo hice, pero sigue dando el mismo problema cuando la recibo en null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mirando la [documentación de indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) veo que se podría hacer así:

```js
let body = '{"Customer":{"Atention":null}}'

function ObtenerValor() {
  var data = JSON.parse(body) //Estoy omitiendo la ruta de la respuesta del JSON
  var cadena = data.Customer.Atention; //está es la ruta del objeto `Atention` en la respuesta del JSON  
  var palabra = 'CARTERA';

  if (cadena == null || cadena.indexOf(palabra) === -1) {
    return "la palabra no existe dentro de la cadena";
  } else {
    return "la palabra existe";
  }
}
console.log(ObtenerValor());
```

Es decir, comprobamos si la `cadena` es **null** por una parte (pues aquí definimos esa variable: `var cadena = data.Customer.Atention;` y tu quieres controlar el posible valor **null**), o bien si el texto no se corresponde con **palabra** mediante esta condición:

```
cadena.indexOf(palabra) === -1
```

aunque ya has dicho que si contiene algo sería "CARTERA", pero por si acaso.

Nota: Leyendo los comentarios veo que es lo mismo que te ha dicho @Mateo

Comment: Sigue dándome el mismo problema

Comment: Ejecuta lo que yo he puesto y verás que funciona. Repasa bien tu código. Piensa que he tenido que abstraerlo para darte esta respuesta, por lo tanto fíjate en las pequeñas diferencias a ver si así lo arreglas.

Comment: jajaja es que no me había fijado que habías quitado `var index = cadena.indexOf(palabra); Excelente ya me funcionó :D mil gracias

Comment: Perfecto, me alegro que te haya funcionado :-)  Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Podrías utilizar un operador ternario, que es básicamente un if en una sola línea, y recibe 3 argumentos, la variable a tomar en cuenta, qué hacer cuando sí se cumple, y qué hacer cuando no se cumple, en este caso si no se cumple (palabra es null), podemos regresar -1, que es lo que indexOf regresaría si no tuviera la palabra

```js
var index = palabra ? cadena.indexOf(palabra) : -1
```

Comment: Hola, me sigue dando el mismo error cuando la recibo en null